# Unique solution vs. exactly one solution for a linear system

Tags: linear-algebra

On one problem I'm doing right now, the problem states that the linear system has a "unique solution". Does that mean it has exactly one solution, or it has at least one solution?

Comment: Unique means exactly one.

Comment: in finite dimensional linear algebra, there are only three possibilities for the number of solutions: zero, one(unique), or infinitely many.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Exact one solution, otherwise it will say solution space.